# Importing Linear Algebra Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to use the following

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import linalg as LA
from np.LA import matrix_power
from np.LA  import multi_dot
```

But am getting the following error:

`File "comp_functions.py", line 9, in <module>
    from np.LA import matrix_power
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'np'`

It's not due to a faulty location as the code in question as I've found to be solution to most other cases on this site as  prior to me adding `from np.LA  import multi_dot`  has been working fine for the following function:

```
def N_eigenvalue(N):
    '''
    Calculates the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a matrix (N) using the linalg module in scipy

    '''


    eigenvalues, eigenvectors = LA.eig(N)
    print(eigenvalues)
    print(eigenvectors)
    return eigenvalues, eigenvectors
```

Comment: In `comp_functions.py` replace `np.LA` with `numpy.LA`

Comment: You're creating a wild mix of namespaces here, where two similar names point to two different modules. Why don't you just import `numpy.linalg` and `scipy.linalg` and use the prefix in you're entire script?

Comment: `np.linalg.multi_dot` is already available once you imported `numpy`.   So is `matrix_power`.  'AS' names like `np` can be used on the `from` side.  `scipy.linalg` does not contain `multi_dot` or `matrix_power`.  This package is meant to be a complement to the `numpy` one, not a duplicate.

Comment: My experience with `numpy` and `scipy` imports is to stick with the documented and conventional patterns.  Don't try to be clever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the version of numpy you are using, in numpy `1.17` it should be imported like this :

```
from numpy.linalg import matrix_power
from numpy.linalg import multi_dot
```

Take a look at [this link](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.matrix_power.html) for more information.